# UVdesk Swiftmailer with Gmail - mail not sending

Tags: swiftmailer

Here's the error message i keep getting.  I have tried setting the php.ini sessions and i still get this error.

I changed the yaml file to connect directly to gmail & confirmed the account.

```
[2022-07-13T01:16:45.625052+00:00] deprecation.INFO: User Deprecated: Since symfony/security-bundle 5.4: Setting
 the $authenticatorManagerEnabled argument of "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DataCollector\SecurityDataCollector
::__construct" to "false" is deprecated, use the new authenticator system instead. {"exception":"[object] (Error
Exception(code: 0): User Deprecated: Since symfony/security-bundle 5.4: Setting the $authenticatorManagerEnabled
 argument of \"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\DataCollector\\SecurityDataCollector::__construct\" to \"false\"
 is deprecated, use the new authenticator system instead. at /var/www/uvdesk/vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Data
Collector/SecurityDataCollector.php:52)"}
```